# Timestamp AT TIME ZONE in SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm getting a strange error when trying to convert `TIMESTAMP` value to a timezone given as parameter (variable).

The code below throws ORA-00907 exception:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
declare
  tz timestamp := current_timestamp;
  v_timezone varchar2(100) := '03:00';
  tz2 timestamp;
begin
--  select (tz at time zone '03:00') into tz2 from dual;
  select (tz at time zone v_timezone) 
    into tz2
    from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(tz2,'hh24:mi:ss'));
--  dbms_output.put_line(to_char((tz at time zone v_timezone),'hh24:mi:ss'));
end;
```

At the same time, both SQL with string literal (first commented line) and PL/SQL with variable (second commented line) work just fine.

What could be the issue with variable in SQL? And why `ORA-00907`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to just enclose the v_timezone variable inside braces (), see your code as below

```
declare
  tz timestamp := current_timestamp;
  v_timezone varchar2(100) := '03:00';
  tz2 timestamp;
begin
  -- select (tz at time zone '03:00') into tz2 from dual;
  -- either use it as 
  -- select tz at time zone (v_timezone)
  -- or
  -- select (tz at time zone (v_timezone) )
  select (tz at time zone (v_timezone) )
    into tz2
    from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(tz2,'hh24:mi:ss'));
--  dbms_output.put_line(to_char((tz at time zone v_timezone),'hh24:mi:ss'));
end;
```

Comment: Even shorter `tz2 := tz at time zone v_timezone;`

Answer (score 4):

[`AT TIME ZONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions007.htm) requires a literal or an expression:

> ```
> expr AT
>    { LOCAL
>    | TIME ZONE { ' [ + | - ] hh:mi'
>                | DBTIMEZONE
>                | 'time_zone_name'
>                | expr
>                }
>    }
> ```

It doesn't like a variable. It seems that the variable is being implicitly seen as an expression inside the `dbms_output` call, or any PL/SQL context (as Wernfried pointed out, just `tz2 := tz at time zone v_timezone` works too), which is a bit strange; but the same thing isn't happening in a SQL context.

You can just force your variable into an expression by enclosing that in parentheses, or call a dummy function:

```
declare
  tz timestamp := current_timestamp;
  v_timezone varchar2(100) := '03:00';
  tz2 timestamp;
begin
--  select (tz at time zone '03:00') into tz2 from dual;
  select tz at time zone (v_timezone) 
    into tz2
    from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(tz2,'hh24:mi:ss'));
--  dbms_output.put_line(to_char((tz at time zone v_timezone),'hh24:mi:ss'));
end;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

17:45:41
```

Essentially, remove the redundant parentheses you have now, and use dummy ones around the variable. You can use a function instead, like `upper(v_timezone)`, but it isn't necessary - just the parentheses to make it be evaluated as an expression are enough. Strange but works... It's mentioned in bug 6113282 and seems to worked like this since 9i.